# Firebase Analytics IOS Error : No known class method for selector 'initiateOnDeviceConversionMeasurementWithPhoneNumber:'

Tags: firebase

Attaching Firebase Analytics to React Native
I built on IOS and got these errors
I've been looking for a workaround, but there isn't much information in the community.
If you know of a solution, please let me know.

```
 "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^18.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.3.0",
 "react-native": "0.71.10",
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for this issue online, I found the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7355).

**This issue has been opened last week.**

You can see that there is a PR for this issue that has been merged and I am assuming this will be part of the next release.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, and after reading your post, can I assume that the problem is caused by my low iOS sdk version?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the current version of the iOS SDK that you are using, but more from the fact that this isn't supported yet. Pending the release of a new version. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: I got it right, thanks for the answer!